# Orchard Module Override a Field Driver

Tags: orchardcms

Hello fellow Orcharders!

I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible, but I want to override the Driver for a single Field in the Module I'm writing.

The Field I want more control over is the Content Picker field. Basically I want the Content Picker to load the shapes for their respective content items. I've looked at [Sipke's Content Picker Widget](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/sfmskywalker/ContentPickerWidget/changeset/2cfc6b211e7d) for an example on how to load shapes, however I'm unsure of the best/recommended approach to implement something similar in my module.

I have the Content Picker Field attached to my Content Part, and the default Content Picker comma list of Content Item titles appears as expected. I have tried to define an Alternate in Placement.info, but I can't load the Content Item shapes from within the Alternate view.

Presumably, as per Sipke's example, these shapes need to be built in the Driver and passed along. If this is correct thing to do, how could I do this in the most Orchard-y way with minimal "hacks". Looking into the debugger, I could "hack" my way to the Field I need in my part's Driver; but the module I'm building will be reused in the future by people unfamiliar with it, and if they start adding/deleting Fields from the Content Part, I'd like everything to behave accordingly!

Of course, if I must take the "hacky" option, I'm willing to do so, but only after I've exhausted all other options. This is my first module, and I've learnt an incredible amount along the way, and I'm really trying to learn the "right" way to build an Orchard Module as best I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read this twice and I still have no clue what you are trying to do or why you think you need to override a driver. Can you please clarify?

Comment: My apologies, I'm not particularly good at putting these things into words; I normally draw pictures when trying to figure it out myself. I'm trying to get the Content Picker field to display the Content Item shapes, rather than just the title of that item with a link. Sipke's Content Picker Widget does this. The rest was to try and provide context (the Content Picker Field is attached to my Content Part).

Comment: So why don't you use Sipke's content picker widget?

Comment: Because I'm creating the module for a client to use, and it needs to be as utterly basic as possible.

The module I'm building could have been done with said Widget, along with Projections or Taxonomies and other built in Orchard features; however for the technically challenged, it's very, very complicated. Hand-holding is a must.